# Way to show post views in while loop?

Tags: widget, wordpress

I have a loop showing post titles and excerpts:

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=blog&showposts=6'); while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="panel">
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<div class="excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
<a class="readmore" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Continue Reading</a>
</div>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

I want to be able to show how many views each post has had in this loop as well.

I am aware there are many ways to show this on the post page (`single.php`), but I cant find any to show it in a loop. Plugins only seem to work on the `single.php` page as well.

Does anyone know a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to find out where the view count are getting stored for each post by the plugin. Generally it gets stored in `post meta`.

If this is the case, Then you need to use the following code to display the view count.

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=blog&showposts=6'); while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="panel">
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

Views for this post: <?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'meta_name_view_count',true); ?>

<div class="excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
<a class="readmore" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Continue Reading</a>
</div>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

`meta_name_view_count` this will be the name what plugin uses to store the view count in `wp_postmeta` table